Send json data to a kafka topic using telegraf
I am trying to send JSON data from a file into a Kafka topic using the Telegraf plugin. However, the format in the file does not match the format being ingested into the topic. I have tried different formats like json, json_v2, value, and adding tag keys, but nothing seems to work.?
sample data
{
"SId": "13",
"last_seen": "2024-07-24T10:30:29.411820+00:00",
"now": "2024-07-24T10:59:51.353953+00:00",
"FITT1565": {
"e": "TRACKSUNSTD",
"r": 4
},
"DIFF_TIME": {
"e": null,
"r": null
},
"FIT04087": {
"e": "TRUE",
"r": 1
},
...
"latest_timestamp": "2024-07-24T10:32:37.211820+00:00"
}
Telegraf config file:
[[inputs.file]]
files = ["/tmp/metrics.json"]
data_format = "json"

[[outputs.kafka]]
brokers = ["kafka.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com:9096"]
topic = "my-topic"
enable_tls = true
data_format = "json"
sasl_username = "user"
sasl_password = "password"
sasl_mechanism = "SCRAM-SHA-512"
insecure_skip_verify = false
ssl_ca = "/etc/telegraf/ca.pem"

Problem:
The data format in the Kafka topic does not match the JSON data I expect. I've tried multiple formats (json, json_v2, and value) and experimented with tag keys, but I'm still having issues.
What alternatives should I try to get the correct format ingested into Kafka? Any help would be appreciated!
